# Redirection webhook when form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web, webhooks

I created a form that works very well, I linked it to a webhook but when the form "works". I'm in front of this page (https://www.jcardonne.com/screen/03PM-12-49_08-05-19) and not in front of the page displayed when it should work normally. (I use integromat)
How to do this?

Thank you very much!
Jean

Comment: You may want to tag your question with **integromat** to make it easier to find it.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy once you figured it out:

At the end of your Integromat scenario you need a **Webhook** module with the action *Webhook response*. Set status to "301" (shows permanent URL redirection) and set the checkbox on "Show advanced settings". Now you see the *Custom headers* part. Create a new entry with the name *Location* and the corresponding URL you want the form user to redirect to.

After the form user has submitted the form the data will be (invisible to the user) by Integromat and finally the user gets redirected to the target URL you have defined.

Note: I have a hidden field in the form that communicates the target URL to integromat. But you can also enter the target URL directly in the Location entry.

[image: Webhook response for URL redirection]

Comment: This really helped me - and I wanted to add that I've expanded on the redirect URL value by adding query parameters - e.g. ?submit=success which I can then use to e.g. render a success message in the page. I think adding a second filter to catch errors would also be useful and an easy addition.